# merging two dataframes only if both values match and belong to the same ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about merging pandas dataframes. I have two dataframes that look like:

df1:

```
chain   cdr3    raw_clonotype_id
TRB CASSARGASGERTDTQYF  clonotype1
TRA CAVSVVRNNNARLMF clonotype1
TRA CAVRGNARLMF clonotype4
TRB CASSLYGTGGSGANVLTF  clonotype4
```

df2:

```
cdr3    chain
CAVSVVRNNNARLMF TRA
CAVRGNARLMF TRA
CASSLYGTGGSGANVLTF  TRB
```

I would like to to merge them on cdr3 but only keep the lines where the clonotype ID for both the chains (TRB and TRA) is a match.

To get a result like this:

```
chain   cdr3    raw_clonotype_id
TRA CAVRGNARLMF clonotype4
TRB CASSLYGTGGSGANVLTF  clonotype4
```

I tried this:

```
df3 = df.merge(df2.groupby('cdr3',as_index=False)[['cdr3']].agg(','.join),how='left')
```

but the output is:

```
cdr3    chain
CAVSVVRNNNARLMF TRA
CAVRGNARLMF TRA
CASSLYGTGGSGANVLTF  TRB
```

I think I just need to add something to the above line but I don't know what.

Comment: do you necessarily have only **up to** 2 values (TRA and TRB) for each clonotype?

Comment: yes, those are the only option, it either has TRA, TRB or both, I only want those with both TRA and TRB

Comment: ok, then my solution below should work ;)

Comment: can you have several cdr3 for a given chain and clonotype? if not, then it shouldn't matter if you filter before or after merging

Comment: you can have different cdr3 for a given chain - for example you can have two diffrent cdr3 for TRB and only one for TRA, ideally I would want to keep both combinations - but your solution below works already, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can first merge, then filter, here using [`GroupBy.transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to ensure having 2 unique values per clonotype (2 receptors):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['cdr3', 'chain'])
df3 = df3[df3.groupby('raw_clonotype_id')['chain'].transform('nunique').eq(2)]
```

output:

```
  chain                cdr3 raw_clonotype_id
1   TRA         CAVRGNARLMF       clonotype4
2   TRB  CASSLYGTGGSGANVLTF       clonotype4
```